# How to download Excel object in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, export-to-excel, excel-interop

Please consider this code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application objApp;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook objBook;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks objBooks;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets objSheets;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet objSheet;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range;

    int ColumnsCount = dt.Columns.Count;
    int RowsCount = dt.Rows.Count;

    objApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    objBooks = objApp.Workbooks;
    objBook = objBooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
    objSheets = objBook.Worksheets;
    objSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)objSheets.get_Item(1);

    for (int i = 1; i < ColumnsCount + 1; i++)
    {
        objSheet.Cells[1, i] = dt.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
    }

    range = objSheet.get_Range("A2", System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
    range = range.get_Resize(RowsCount, ColumnsCount);

    string[,] saRet = new string[RowsCount, ColumnsCount];

    for (int iRow = 0; iRow < RowsCount; iRow++)
    {
        for (int iCol = 0; iCol < ColumnsCount; iCol++)
        {
            saRet[iRow, iCol] = dt.Rows[iRow][iCol].ToString();
        }
    }

    //Set the range value to the array.
    range.set_Value(Missing.Value, saRet);
```

I want to download Excel object that I created. The problem is `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook` is not serializable and until I save it I can't access Excel file. How I can download Excel that created in memory?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like one of the many problems related to [Microsoft KB: Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757). Using Excel Interop server-side isn't supported.

I'd recommend you export csv files or look into OpenXML or the easier version [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com) to generate xslx files on the server.

See the other methods in this MSDN guide: [How To Asp.Net Export Excel](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/erikaehrli/archive/2009/01/30/how-to-export-data-to-excel-from-an-asp-net-application-avoid-the-file-format-differ-prompt.aspx)

Comment: Is there a way to create Excel using OpenXML and download it using asp.net?

Comment: Yes, do a quick search on OpenXML to create xslx's and see the edit to my question with an MSDN guide on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a SaveAs method on your workbook that you can use to save as an xls file.

```
objBook.SaveAs("my-workbook.xls");
```

Comment: I don't want to save it.Currently I haven't a folder for save my file on the server